# Proof of matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a symmetric, negative definite matrix $H\in\mathbb R^{n\ \times\ n}; n\in\mathbb N$, a vector $v\in\mathbb R^n$ and a scalar $c\in\mathbb R$. For any $H,v$, does a $c>0$ exist for which

\begin{equation}
c \cdot H = H \cdot v \cdot v^T \cdot H
\end{equation}

holds?

**EDIT:**

I thought that the equation follows from my original equation, but apparently this is not the case. So what I originally wanted to show, is that

\begin{equation}
-c \cdot H \cdot v = -\left(  H + \frac{ H \cdot v \cdot v^T \cdot H}{ f - v^T \cdot H \cdot v } \right) \cdot v
\end{equation}

holds, where $f\in\mathbb R, f>0$, for a $c>0$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no in general.  In particular, $Hvv^TH$ will necessarily be a matrix of rank at most $1$, so that we can only find such a $v$ if the rank of $H$ is $1$.

Comment: Check out my answer: Have an error there?

Comment: @Make42 yes: $cHv = Hvv^THv$ does not imply that $cH = Hvv^TH$.

Comment: And the other way around?

Comment: Yes, it is true that $cH = Hvv^TH$ implies that $cHv = Hvv^THv$, but this is only so helpful.  You may conclude from your analysis that **if** such a non-zero scalar $c$ exists, then it must satisfy $c = v^THv$.

Comment: The equation I posted is already a couple of steps down in my proof. According to you I already made mistakes, so I post the original equation in the question. Maybe you can check it out.

Comment: @Make42 I don't have time to really think about it, but the expression in your updated question reminds me of the [Sherman-Morrison formula,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) perhaps that helps.

Comment: The reason is, that I got the equation by applying Sherman-Morrison to other equations ;-).

Answer (score 0):

We use that $H$ is negative definite and a $c_2\in\mathbb R, c_2>0$:

\begin{align}
c_1 \cdot H &= H \cdot v \cdot v^T \cdot H \\
c_1 \cdot H \cdot v &= H \cdot v \cdot v^T \cdot H \cdot v \\
c_1 \cdot H \cdot v &= H \cdot v \cdot (-c_2) \\
-\frac{c_1}{c_2} \cdot H \cdot v &= H \cdot v \\
\end{align}

so we require $c_1 = -c_2 = v^T \cdot H \cdot v < 0$.

So, a $c>0$ does not exist for which the equation from the question holds, but a $c<$ does exist.